# Replication or Message Queue?

Tags: replication, message-queue

my application (in US) is generating data to one of the tables in database (20 record/min)
i want to replicate the data incrementally to server located in Germany
Whats the best solution to incrementally replicate those records newly added. (Application like messaging queue or using SQL Server replication)

Is there any incremental replication exists in SQL server that also zipping data for best performance or i should do it with custom application for gaining better berformance ???

Answer (score 0):

My answer would depend upon your current application architecture.

Are you already using a message queue or other middleware layer?  If so, then it should be fairly straightforward to duplicate those messages for a cross-ocean queue.  If you do not have such a layer, then adding one is likely going to add complexity that is unwarranted.

Otherwise, most database systems have a replication engine of some sort.  You don't actually specify, but I am guessing Microsoft SQL server in this case?

Unless your data is quite large, 20 updates per minute should not tax any replication scheme, nor cross ocean link; "zip"ped or otherwise for that matter.  Zip or other compression schemes will help the most if your data is sparse or repetitive, is it mostly text?  If numeric and a mix of data in those 20 records, the savings will not be as large.

Good Luck